# Write a stored procedure which reads from table A and writes into table B in PostgreSQL

Tags: plsql, plpgsql

Using PL/SQL or plpgsql in PostgreSQL, I need to write a stored procedure that reads from Table A and writes into Table B. Both these tables have the same structure and the procedure will not have any arguments. I'm not exactly sure what this would look like. Thanks!

Comment: Will you know the table definitions in advance, or are you supposed to figure that out programmatically?

Comment: If there are no arguments to the procedure, does that mean you're just copying all records from Table A into Table B?  If not, how will you know which records to copy?

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be as simple as the PL/SQL script below. If there are additional requirements, let me know.

```
create table temp_a (
  id number,
  my_data varchar2(100),
  data_date date);

insert into temp_a (id, my_data, data_date)
values (1, 'some data', sysdate);

select * from temp_a;

create table temp_b (
  id number,
  my_data varchar2(100),
  data_date date);

select * from temp_b;

create or replace procedure copy_data is
begin
  insert into temp_b (id, my_data, data_date)
  select id, my_data, data_date from temp_a;
end;
/

begin copy_data; end;

select * from temp_a;

select * from temp_b;
```